# Can Amazon Athena be used to query a dynamic schema?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a service running that populates my S3 bucket with the compressed log files, but the log files do not have a fixed schema and athena expects a fixed schema. (Which I wrote while creating the table)

So my question is as in the title, is there any way around through which I can query a dynamic schema? If not is there any other service like athena to do the same thing?

Comment: Do the files contain information about the schema that was used? Some file formats (eg Parquet and ORC) include schema information within the file. Would you know the schema at the time of the query?

Comment: Not right now. But what if I convert the data (currently json) to Parquet?

Comment: JSON data also has a loose schema, which might be sufficient for your needs. Parquet would most probably work too. I would recommend some experimentation on a sample datafile.

Comment: Sorry if its a dumb question, but how do I infer schema from my JSON data to update the existing schema on Athena?

Comment: Hmm. Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/json.html), you'd need to know the fields that are in the file (or at least the ones you want to use), but that would be necessary to run a query anyway. Feel free to Edit your question to provide some examples -- somebody might be able to assist.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon Athena can't do that by itself, but you can configure an [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/) crawler to automatically infer the schema of your JSON files. The crawler can [run on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html#schema-crawlers-schedule), so your files will be indexed automatically even if the schema changes. [Athena will use the Glue data catalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-athena.html) if AWS Glue is [available in the region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#glue_region) you're running Athena in.

See [Cataloging Tables with a Crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html) in the AWS Glue docs for the details on how to set that up.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply! 

Will look into this but my team ended up creating something of our own for faster log grepping. It's been one year now and it's working fine.

Comment: Also, since you can also combine the crawler with Glue's ETL features, it might be worth looking into if you ever need to enrich or modify your data to allow different queries.